# Platform for high performance 3d coverflow UI in browser

Tags: silverlight, graphics, 3d, browser

Im writing an application for embedded device that can display 3d coverflow like ui.

Requirements
1. High performance (60fps, preferably GPU accelerated)
2. Run in browser.
3. Supported in linux(android if possible).

Im not familiar with web/browser technology, but im familiar with .net/wpf and little silverlight. Ive tested multiple silverlight coverflow and perspective correct transformation is a bit laggy. the best implementation imho can be seen here http://coverflow.darickcarpenter.net/. it has virtualization, perspective correct. performance could be improve by disabling transparency altogether. im not sure if its gpu accelerated. im not sure how much performance can be squeeze from silverlight.

What platform/technology has the best 3d rendering performance in browser?

Edit. I just found a guy implement 2 similar coverflow in silverlight and javascript(webkit). Performance wise, javascript is extremely fluid. I thought since silverlight is created by microsoft, running silverlight in ie provides best performance. I thought silverlight 5 have gpu rendering support. Any opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choice WebGL/HTML5 for near future browser technologies with attention to high performance.. It's also usable for most mobile devices with android right now..

So you might start with this pretty implementation in WebGL (also contains code) http://www.coconnut.com/blog/2012/07/25/html5-javascript-webgl-ejemplo-de-galeria-con-menu-tipo-coverflow/ .